# Call ajax on dropdown button

Tags: python, ajax, django

I've created a form and populating its value from `Category` model in drop down box. Its working.
I displayed this form in template like this `{{ language_form }}`.It worked. Now I want to implement `onchange` event on this drop down with ajax. Function will call on change of drop down value.

Edit:it can be done like this without django forms . `<select onchange='ajaxfunction()'></select>` But I'm using django forms.

Form

```
from django import forms
from myapp.movie.models import Category
class Language(forms.Form):
     language = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all())
```

Here is my Ajax function

```
   function showMovie(str) {
        if (str == "") {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        }
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "movie_list?q=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to just add `onchange` attr, then:

```
class Language(forms.Form):
    language = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all(), widget=forms.Select(attrs={'onchange':'ajaxfunction()'}))
```

Or you can render form manually.

Comment: Thanks. One this . Is it correct `widget=forms.Select(attrs={'onchange':'ajaxfunction(this.value)'})` ? Want to pass selected value.

Comment: @user559744 Yes, it's just a string.

Comment: oh ok. But I want to send selected drop box value.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in the end of your form.

```
...
</form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var ddl = document.getElementById('ddlYourDropDownListID');
        ddl.onchange = function() {
            var str = 'someValue';
            showMovie(str);
        };
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```